# What do masters really know about their slaves?

Tags: c#, communication, network-protocols

I have my devices in Master/Slave configuration and I'm developing a WPF/MVVM application.

I have a COM objects (all which implement `IDevice`) which represent the state of a external device/Modbus network and is attached to something like `SerialPort` or `Socket`.  What this means is that, after identifying a device by its `Version` and `Revision`, I call `IDevice device = DeviceManager.GetDevice(version, revision);` to get an object which represents the state of a factory default device.

Now that I have a `IDevice`, I can call its API to get things like `List<ushort> GetCoreRegisters()` and `List<ushort> GetAllRegisters()`.  With that being said, after reading register values, I have to call `IDevice`'s API to set the values: `device.SetItemValue(registerAddress, registerValue)` in order to update the state of the device on the other side of the network.

I have created a `Master` type which deals with the communication layer (`Socket` vs. `SerialPort`).

In the current state of my application, I call something like the following pseudo code in one of my view models (after a button is clicked):

```
IDevice device = null;
profile = SelectedProfile
master = MasterFactory.GetMaster(profile.Name)
master.Open() //Connects or Opens SerialPort/Socket
if(master.DeviceCheck(profile.SlaveAddress))
{
    KeyValuePair<ushort, ushort> info = await master.IdentifyDeviceAsync(profile.SlaveAddress);
    device = DeviceManager.GetDevice(info.Key, info.Value)
    initList = device.GetInitializationRegisters()
    initValues = await master.ReadRegisters(profile.SlaveAddress, initList)
    for(int i = 0; i < initList; i++)
        device.SetRegisterValue(initList[i], initValues[i]);

    allRegisters = device.GetAllRegisters();
    allValues = await master.ReadRegisters(profileSlaveAddress, allRegisters)
    for ... repeat
}
if device != null, DevicesInViewModel.Add(device)
master.Close()
```

My question is, is this correct design, or should I have a `List<IDevice> Devices` in `Master` and after identifying device(s), I would do something more like:

```
device = DeviceManager.GetDevice(info.Key, info.Value);
master.Add(device);
// possibly add more devices if needed
List<IDevice> devices = master.ReadDevices()
if devices != null, DevicesInViewModel.AddRange(devices);
```

Where all of the `GetRegister` and `SetRegisterValue` logic is inside `Master`--meaning Master knows everything about `IDevice` and handles the logic of configuring the state of the slaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View model code, in an ideal world, is pretty simple. You certainly don't want to be running long operations and loops in it. The view model contains logic for handling commands from the view, that's it.

Your first example seems to have quite a bit of domain knowledge and business logic in it. That should go *somewhere* in the model. From what I can see, your `Master` class seems a reasonable place to put it.

To answer the titular question: Masters know quite a bit about their slaves, certainly enough to "drive" or "use" them. Thus, it knowing about everything in `IDevice` is ok. Make sure its generic though, the master shouldn't know *what type* of slave he is dealing with.